# How to validate a text-field only if data present?

Tags: vuetify.js

I've a `text-field` which accepts a facebook URL. The user can either leave it blank or enter a value. How can I achieve that using Vuetify validations?

**template**

```
 <div>            
        <v-text-field outline                      
                      v-model="socialMediaAccounts.facebook"
                      :rules="facebookUrlRules"
                      append-icon="fa-facebook"></v-text-field>          
 </div>
```

**script**

```
data() {
        return {                
            facebookUrlRules: [
                f => this.regexMatchesText('facebook', f) || 'Enter a valid facebook url'
            ]
        }
    },

methods: {
        regexMatchesText(socialMedium, url) {
            let regEx = {
                facebook: /(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?([\w\-]*)?/

            };
            let checker = new RegExp(regEx[socialMedium]);
            return checker.test(url);
        }
    },
```

The code is checking for a valid url but, also displays error msg if I leave the text-field blank. Is there any way to check a valid entry or blank?

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/paanoop/pen/mGJYgY)

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very simple:

```
gstRules: [n => !n || this.regexMatchesTextGst(n) || 'Invalid gst format'],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f => !f ? true : this.regexMatchesText('facebook', f) || 'Enter a valid facebook url'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably very much not relevant to original person but... 
heres how i got it to work:

Damien Spivak was very close.
***Important part there is the Wrapper of 

    `( blah blah ) || 'error message str'
    f => (!f ? true : this.regexMatchesText('facebook', f)) || 'Enter a valid facebook url'`